# Mostrar un circulo cuando enfoco la cámara

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, cámara

Estoy intentado mostrar un circulo cuando toco la UIView para enfocar la cámara. Ya pude lograr el enfoque pero no logro crear ese circulo. Como ejemplo puede ser la cámara de Instagram, cuando tocas en un punto de la pantalla puedes ver un circulo que se crea en el punto del toque. Como puedo hacer esto.

Actualmente estoy usando `touchesBegan`para activar el enfoque. Este es mi código del enfoque:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let screeSnSize = cameraView.bounds.size
    if let touchPoint = touches.first {

        let x = touchPoint.location(in: cameraView).y / screeSnSize.height
        let y = 1.0 - touchPoint.location(in: cameraView).x / screeSnSize.width
        let focusPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        let cameraPosition = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        if let device = cameraPosition {

            do {

                try? device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
                device.focusMode = .autoFocus
                device.exposurePointOfInterest = focusPoint
                device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.continuousAutoExposure
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
                print("focus is active")

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Código:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var circle: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    view.alpha = 0.0
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.height / 2
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    return view
  }()

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    if let touch = touches.first {
      let locationOfTouch = touch.location(in: self.view)

      showCircle(inPosition: locationOfTouch)
    }
  }

  func showCircle(inPosition newPosition: CGPoint) {
    circle.center = newPosition
    circle.alpha = 0.0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
      self.circle.alpha = 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

## Actualizado:

```
extension ViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // .. otro codigo

    // comenta o borra esta linea de tu codigo
    //self.cameraView.addSubview(circle)

    // agrega esta linea de codigo
    self.view.addSubview(circle)

    // .. otro codigo
  }
}
```

Si no te entendí mal, creo que te podría ayudar esta solución.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55226/discussion-on-answer-by-wilson-mostrar-un-circulo-cuando-enfoco-la-camara).